# Convergence in a Tychonoff space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X = \prod_{j \in J} X_j$, where $X_j$ are topological spaces, and $X$ is a Tychonoff space. Let $P_j$ be the projections of $X$ in $X_j$. Let $(x_n)_n$ be an sequence in $X$. prove that

$$x_n \rightarrow x \:\textrm{ if and only if }\: P_j(x_n) \rightarrow P_j(x)$$

Thank you.

Comment: For the backward direction, try a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Let me ask you a question: if $Y$ is a topological space, $y$ a point in $Y$, and $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a sequence of elements in $Y$; what is the meaning of "$y_n\to y$"? If you can answer me, then you probably know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that we have Tychonoff spaces is irrelevant.

For notational clarity, I'll denote by $f$ or $f_n$ elements of $X$ (they're functions with domain $J$). And the projection maps $p_j$ are just evaluations, i.e. $p_j(f) = f(j)$.

First observe that all projection maps $p_j: X \to X_j$ are continuous, and thus are sequentially continuous, i.e. $(f_n)_n \to f$ in $X$ implies $p_j(f_n) \to \pi_j(f)$ for all $j \in J$.

Now, assume that for all $j$ we have $p_j(f_n) \to p_j(f)$ for a sequence $(f_n)_n$ in $X$ and some $f \in X$.

Now, let $U$ be a basic open neighbourhood of $f$, so $f \in U = \prod_{j \in J} U_j$ where all $U_j$ are open and there is some *finite* $F \subseteq J$ such that $U_j = X_j$ for all $j \notin F$.

Now for each $j \in F$ we note that $f(j)= p_j(f)$ is in $U_j$ and as we have convergence per coordinate, there is some $N_j \in \Bbb N$ such that

$$\forall n \ge N_j: f_n(j)=p_j(f_n) \in U_j$$

Because we have finitely many $N_j, j \in F$, we can define $N = \max_{j \in F} N_j$ and for all $n \ge N$ and any $j \in J$ we have that $p_j(f_n) = f_n(j) \in U_j$ when $j \notin F$ (trivially) and also $n \ge N_j$ so $p_j(f)= f_n(j) \in U_j$ for $j \in F$. So

$$\forall n \ge N: f_n \in U$$

and as $U$ was an arbitrary basic open neighbourhood of $f$, we have shown $f_n \to f$, as required.